# Change of Basis Matrix: Cartesian to Spherical Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, coordinate-systems

I was looking at how a change of basis matrix, $[P_{\beta\leftarrow\alpha}]$, is made. While this is a bit more advanced that than what was taught at the course, I wonder what would be the change of basis matrix of the Laplacian from Cartesian coordinates to spherical ones.

I use the Laplacian in spherical coordinates a lot. It's as common as the plague for the 3-dimensional Schrodinger equation, but I see it kind of depressing how I don't know the underlying beauty of such a thing.

Comment: What do you mean with "change of basis matrix". The transformation from cartesian to polar is not linear. To find the Laplacian in new coordinates just use the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

Does Sect. 1.4 on this page answer your question?
http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En221/Notes/Polar_Coords/Polar_Coords.htm
(The site's author is most likely Prof. A.F. Bower.)